# Return whether or not each x in String str is immediately followed by an o

Tags: java

```
public class XO {
  public boolean main(String str) {
    // Your code here
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
      if (str.charAt(i)=='x'){
        if (str.charAt(i+1)=='o'){
          return true;
         } else {
          return false;
         }
      }
    }
    return false;    
  }
}
```

[image]

what am i doing wrong? some tests are  not passed.

Comment: The screenshot shows clearly which two tests fail for you. Do you understand what they are trying to test?

Comment: 1) You return only on finding the first `x`... 2) You probably should be using `str.length()-2` if you want to do `charAt(i+1)`. 3) your loop doesn't run for an empty or null string, so you dont want to return false (or that test is wrong). Also unclear what the value should be for no `x`, but seems to want to return true

Comment: If there are multiple xs or no xs in the string, what should your code do? What does it actually do?

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to learn about breakpoints and a debugger, or unit tests of your own rather than those provided. For extra reading see [How to Debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In your screenshot it says `main("o")` is returning `true` but in your code you're returning `false`. Probably you're not saving the latest version? Your code runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Return whether or not each x in String str is immediately followed by an o

Remember you need to go thru the entire string to determine total compliance but just one failure is all you need for non-compliance. To do this
you want to do is check when the situation is `not true` and return `false`.  If you get thru the loop successfully you need check that the last character is not a lone `x`.  I am also presuming an empty string returns `true`.

```
for (...) {
   if (str.charAt(i)=='x' && str.charAt(i + 1) !='o') {
          return false;
   }
}

return !str.endsWith("x");
```

(Thanks to [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) for pointing out this last border case).

An here is another approach using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-) to simply check to see if an `x` exists that is not followed by an `o`

-`(?!o)` - not followed by an `o`

```
public static boolean check(String s) {
     return !Pattern.compile("x(?!o)").matcher(s).find();
}
```

Comment: Your condition isn't quite right: you need to handle an X at the end of the string too, e.g. `str.charAt(i) == 'x' && (i+1 >= str.length() || str.charAt(i + 1) !='o'`) (and the loop guard would need updating too to check that)

Comment: Yeah, I was more in tune with explaining checking for failure than success I was bitten by a border case.

Comment: @AndyTurner I came up with a way of doing it at the end.  It seems to pass all my test cases.  Thanks for the observation.

Comment: if you're putting the "ends with X" check in the final return, it would be easier just to use `!str.endsWith("X")`, which handles the empty case.

Answer (score -1):

Your `main()` method should be void and should take a String array parameter. You can't return a Boolean value from a void method.

I've also simplified the logic of your `if/else` conditional:

```
public class XO {
  public boolean oFollowsX(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i)=='x' && str.charAt(i + 1)=='o') {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    XO xo = new XO();
    System.out.println(xo.oFollowsX("axo"));
    System.out.println(xo.oFollowsX("oxen"));
    System.out.println(xo.oFollowsX("exotic"));
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong. You are returning true when you find the first X followed by O; instead, you want to return false when you find the first X *not* followed by O. (And the thing about the void main method isn't relevant, OP's screenshot shows that the tests were running as it was, presumably it is some testing framework).